# Duplicate Elimination Using Sets in Java

Tags: java, duplicates, set

Write a program that reads in a series of first names and eliminates duplicates by storing them in a Set. Allow the user to search for a first name.

(Trust me, I am not taking any Java classes. So, not my homework).

My issue is to implement this: **Allow the user to search for a first name.**

Everything else works, just the search feature.

*My Code so far....*

```
package com.Sets;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class DuplicateElimination {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Write a program thats ask for first names and store it in an array.

        String fName;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] names = new String[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter First Name: ");
            names[i] = input.nextLine();
        }
        // Printout that array as a list.
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(names);

        // Initial Array Elements
        System.out.printf("%s ", list);
        System.out.println();

        // Calling removeDuplicates method
        removeDuplicates(list);

    }

    // Make a method called removeDuplicates.
    private static void removeDuplicates(Collection<String> values) {

        // Implement a Hashset in it.
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(values);

        // Printout a non-duplicate list of elements.
        for (String value : set) {
            System.out.printf("%s ", value);
        }

        System.out.println();

    }

    // Make a method to search for a first name.
    public static void searchForName(Collection<String> names) {

        String someName;

        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(names);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Search this name: ");
            someName = input.nextLine();
        }

        if (someName ) {

        } else {

        }
    }

}
```

I don't feel confident about my searchForName method... can someone give an idea on how I could make this work?

Comment: What is a first name? First inserted of first alphabetically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `set.contains()` method to check if a set contains the input string.

```
   for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Search this name: ");
            someName = input.nextLine();
        }

if(set.contains(someName)) {
System.out.println("set contains name");

}
else {
System.out.println("set doesnt contain this name");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider having `removeDuplicates` return the `Set`. Pass the `Set` to `searchForName`. Then just use `Set.contains`.

[Set.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean searchForName(Collection<String> names, String someName) 
{
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(names);
    return set.contains(someName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use A TreeSet, and then use [tailSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#tailSet%28E,%20boolean%29) and [headSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#headSet%28E,%20boolean%29)
to find all the elemnents "greater or equal than" and "less or equal than" your search key in alphabetical order.

```
final TreeSet<String> p = new TreeSet<String>();

        p.addAll(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "aaaaaa", "bbbbbbb", "cccccc", "dddddd", "eeeeeee", "fffff" }));

        System.out.println(p.headSet("dd", true));
        System.out.println(p.tailSet("dd", true));
```

Result:

```
[aaaaaa, bbbbbbb, cccccc]
[dddddd, eeeeeee, fffff]
```

The first element of the tailSet is the key starting with your search key ("dd").
There is a catch - if the surname "dddddd" was not found, tailSet would return:

```
[eeeeeee, fffff]
```

so you always have to check if the first element startsWith("dd") else notFound!